# Reading an excel file into a pandas DF that has a pipe and spaces as delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delimiter

How can I read an excel file into a pandas dataframe that has a pipe and a space as delimiters?

The code I'm currently using is:

```
DF = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\Automation\File.xls', sep="|")
```

I don't know how to add the space as the second delimiter, I have also tried `\s+|` but to no avail.

```
ID|Name|Job|Nationality|
123 Cian|IT|-|
222 John|Teacher|Spanish|
```

Comment: Is it pipe followed by a space or the seperator can be either a pipe or a space. Can you give an example?

Comment: Have you tried pandas.read_excel https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html ?

Comment: @Mohammad it is a pipe or a space yes. I have added an example of the data above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex in the `sep` field:

```
my_file = '''
ID|Name|Job|Nationality|

123 Cian|IT|-|

222 John|Teacher|Spanish|
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(my_file), sep='[ |]')
```

Comment: Great thank you, that was very nicely done